Dirac functions normalization factor in spherical coordinates
I have the following expression $\frac{\delta(r-R)\delta(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})[H(\phi)-H(\phi+\pi)]}{r\sin\theta}$. Apparently the factor of   $\,\,r\sin\theta$ in the denominator arises as a normalization factor from the delta functions since spherical coordinates are not a euclidian space. I would very much like an explanation demonstrating exactly why the factor is $\,\,r\sin\theta$ as I am failing to understand it.
Thanks in advance to all who answer.

What is this expression supposed to represent? Nobody can tell you what it should or shouldn’t be without more context

The expression comes from an expression for current density in space through a semi-circle. I have been told however by course staff that the factor simply rises from the use of the delta functions in this expression
